# jQPlot charts- Pie chart disappears on passing high values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

When i run the code the chart disappears

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var d1=${views};
    var d2=${comoneviews};
    var d3=${comtwoviews};
    var plot1 = $.jqplot('piechart', [[['Your Organisation',d1],['Competitor#1',d2],['Competitor#2',d3]]], {
        gridPadding: {top:0, bottom:38, left:0, right:0},
        seriesDefaults:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
            trendline:{ show:false }, 
            rendererOptions: { padding: 7, showDataLabels: true ,  dataLabels: 'value'}
        },
        legend:{
            show:true, 
            placement: 'outside', 
            rendererOptions: {
                numberRows: 1
            }, 
            location:'s',
            marginTop: '15px'
        }       
    }); 
});
```

the input values i am getting for d1 is 20700000 , d2 is 2300000, and d3 is 3040000. So does the chart does not appear because of higher values?

Comment: Your code looks fine... See [here](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/xEPJWZ?editors=1111). The issue you have is somewhere else.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Actually what is happening is in d1,d2,d3 i am getting a array like d1=[20700000] i think that is making a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your comment, you just need to refer to the **d1**,**d2** and **d3** array values correctly. As you've mentioned, you are getting them as arrays - so the problem must be with your access to the actual values.

Access them as `d1[0]` `d2[0]` `d3[0]` (assuming you have a one sized array like you wrote)

```
var d1=[20700000];
var d2=[2300000];
var d3=[3040000];
var plot1 = $.jqplot('piechart', [[['Your Organisation',d1[0]],
['Competitor#1',d2[0]],['Competitor#2',d3[0]]]], {
     ...rest of plot code...
```

here is a [working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kkvPZK?editors=1111) with d1-d3 modified to arrays.

Comment: I figured out the problem ..but thanks for conforming it!